# ASP MVC URL Action in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have this on Razor page

Index.cshtml

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
 {
 var cars = Model.ElementAt(i); 
 <a href="@Url.Action("Cars","Home", new { id = cars.Id })">
 }
```

And I want to replace this in javascript using Jquery Ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "Get",
    url: '/Cars/Home',
    data: {
        id: $(this).attr("id")
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {             
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            html1.push("<a href='Cars/Home', new { id = cars.Id })>");
            html1.push("</a>");
        }
        $("#wraps").html(html1.join(""));
    }
})
```

This give me an error. However, how can I do this thing?

Comment: There are a few things possibly wrong here. What error are you getting?

Comment: @MikeC 
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult

Comment: Is it other ways to do it then? I mean using @Url.Action in JS in <a href..

Comment: Okay, sounds like there's a bit of a misunderstanding about how to get your data then. You need to create a [web API endpoint](http://www.asp.net/web-api) then gives you the data you need. Then your AJAX call needs to point to that endpoint. Finally, don't use `new { id = cars.Id }`, that's C# syntax. Assign the ID just like you would if you wrote the HTML by hand.

Comment: @MikeC Thank you. I'll look at it.

Comment: @MikeC Otherwise why should I use Web API to handle the data? It is not API i'm working with. I'm just passing data from controller to view using Jquery Ajax to print out the data with HTML. By the way, i found the solution.  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {html1.push("<a href='Home/Cars?id=" + [i + 1] + "'>");. i can now access the links with the correct ID's.

Comment: Your ajax call appears odd. You are telling it to get `/Cars/Home/{id}`, and then when it returns, you assume the `data` it returns has some length, but you are not even using the actual `data`, and instead you are just creating a number of links to `/Cars/Home/{someId}` (based on the length of `data`. What does your `/Cars/Home/{id}` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax call appears odd. You are telling it to get `/Cars/Home/{id}`, and then when it returns, you are creating a number of links to `/Cars/Home/{someId}` (based on the length of `data`), but you are not really using the content of `data`.

I assume you want to send an HttpGet to `/Cars/Home/` (without passing an `id`), and I assume this returns an `IEnumerable` (list) of a type (e.g. `Car`), and then create all the links to the details page of each of that type, all using js. If so, you could do this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/Cars/Home',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {             
        var links = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var car = data[i];                
            links.push("<a href='/Cars/Home/" + car.Id + "'>Link to Car Id " + car.Id + "</a>");
        }
        $("#wraps").html(links.join(''));
    }
})
```